# Dynamic form ng-pattern based off sibling <select> option in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have a form with 2 elements, a dropdown and a text box.
I want to match the text box with $pattern but be able to choose my $pattern depending on the selection made in the first form control.

A simple abstracted example of what I'm aiming at:

```
<form>
    <select>
        <option>A-Z</option>
        <option>0-9</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" pattern="{{[A-Z]}}"/>
    <input type="text" pattern="{{[0-9]}}"/>
</form>
```

I don't mind having both inputs and using ng-show but would rather have one and swap the pattern. How would you really achieve this effect in Angular?

---

Thank you for your reply, it got me a lot closer, but I am slightly more complicated in that I really need a 3-way data binding (i think?)

I have a model for the select element:

```
$scope.myModel = [
 {id: 'abc', value: 'foo'},
 {id: 'def', value: 'bar'}
]
```

and an object with corresponding keys:

```
var myObj = {
    abc: /^\d{3}$/,
    def: /^\d{4}$/
};

$scope.validationPattern = myObj[$scope.myModel.id];
```

I build my select element from the model:

and an input:

```
<input name="myfield" id="myfield"
      ng-model="myModel"
      ng-pattern="validationPattern"
      required 
/>
```

validation pattern gets set initially but changing the option in the select doesn't cause it to update.

Ultimately if a user selects foo in the dropdown the input should only accept 3 digits.

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('App', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  this.patterns = ['[A-Z]', '[0-9]'];
  
  this.pattern = this.patterns[0];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form ng-app="App" ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  <select ng-model="main.pattern" ng-options="pattern for pattern in main.patterns">
  </select>

<input type="text" ng-attr-pattern="{{main.pattern}}"/>
```